# ruby dk.rb install: Must Edit Config File

Tags: ruby, devkit

So I got all my ruby plugins and interpretor running about week ago. I don't know what happened, but my ide fails when I try to run scripts. So I'm starting over with these instructions 
https://www.agiletrailblazers.com/blog/the-5-step-guide-for-selenium-cucumber-and-gherkin

I installed Ruby 2.3.3 without the  devkit

I downloaded and extracted the devkit to C:\Ruby23-x64

I run 'ruby dk.rb init' via command line in C:\Ruby23-x64 and it says
[image]

My config file looks like this

[image]

What am I supposed to edit in my config file? I tried using forward slashes instead of back slashes. I got this output.
[image]

What the heck am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your PATH environment variable is pointing to wrong locations, you apparently had Ruby 2.4 installed at one point. And devkit is practically a requirement on Windows if you want to run C extensions.

Comment: I did have Ruby 2.4. I deleted it because the ruby dk commands weren't working and opted to install the installer and dev kit separately. If I remove it from my config file, I should be good to move along, because 2.4 is already removed from my files

Comment: If I delete 2.4 from my config file my output becomes 

[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby23-x64'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby23-x64'

Comment: Where is devkit currently installed?

Comment: It's located in this path. C:\Ruby23-x64

Comment: I'm thinking there is still something I need to do for 'ruby dk.rb init'. I installed my gems. If I run an rb file that is supposed to run some actions, it will only open the browser and that's it

Comment: `[ERROR] Skipping invalid directory 'C:/Ruby24-x64'` It is still trying old directory. Going to guess that it should not even be trying to or have any knowledge of any Ruby24 installation on your machine. That fact that it does means your paths are screwed up. `dk.rb` isn't making up that path by itself.

Comment: Hmmm...well I guess at least I know what the issue is now. Thanks!  :/